# Propiedad de un constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, objeto, prototipos

El prototipo de un constructor, es una función. Entonces, ¿por qué en este caso me arroja `false`?

```js
function A() {
  this.n = 15;
}

A.prototype = {b: 2, c: 3};

Function.prototype.nn = 15;

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(A));

console.log(A.hasOwnProperty("n")); // false porque está heredado

console.log(A.hasOwnProperty("b")); // Falso porque declaramos su prototipo

console.log(A.hasOwnProperty("nn"));  // False?? por que?
```

***Mi problema está en el ultimo `console.log()`. ¿Cuál es el error en mis conceptos?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos a poner como ejemplo el siguiente código:

```js
function A() {
  this.atr1 = 1;
};

A.prototype = {atr2: 2, atr3: 3};

Function.prototype.atr4 = 4;

var a = new A();
```

En dicho código tenemos lo siguientes objetos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- ***Constructor A***: es una función que será usada como constructor para crear instancias de nuevos objetos. A pesar de ser una función es también un objeto.
- ***A.prototipo***: es el objeto prototipo de A que es creado automáticamente al definir la función A. Dicho objeto será el `__proto__` ascendente de toda instancia de objeto creada a partir del constructor A.
- ***Objeto a***: es una instancia de un objeto creada a partir del constructor A. Este objeto tendrá inicialmente los atributos definidos con `this` en el momento de crearse con `new A()` ya que ejecuta la función `A()` siendo `this` el objeto `a` recién creado. Automáticamente el `__proto__` de este objeto será `A.prototype`.
- ***Function***: Es la función constructor usada implícitamente en la creación de cualquier función. Por lo tanto, el prototipo de `Function` (`Function.prototype`) se asigna automáticamente como el `__proto__` de cualquier función creada.

Cuando se intenta acceder a un atributo de un objeto, JS primero mira si dicho atributo está dentro del propio objeto. Si no lo encuentra, entonces empieza a recorrer los `__proto__` padre sucesivamente hasta que encuentra el atributo.

En este ejemplo, si intento acceder a `a.atr2`, al no estar este atributo dentro de `a` pero sí en el `__proto__` de `a` (`A.prototype`), devolvería su valor: 2.

La función `hasOwnProperty()` comprueba si una propiedad está dentro de un objeto, pero sólo dentro del objeto. Si la propiedad no está dentro del objeto pero es accesible a través de su `__proto__`, la función `hasOwnProperty()` devolvería `false`.

Por lo tanto, en tu código estás intentando comprobar si el objeto `A()` tiene una serie de propiedades directas y, como puedes ver, ninguna de ellas está dentro de `A()`.

Para ello tendrías que haber hecho algo así: `A.atr1 = 10`. Aquí `atr1` sí sería una propiedad de objeto `A()`, y devolvería `true` si se hace `A.hasOwnProperty("atr1")`.

---

*Pásate por aquí para entender mejor el tema de objetos en JS. http://www.objectplayground.com/*

Answer (score 0):

`hasOwnProperty` es un método que se utiliza específicamente para objetos, en tu ejemplo `A` es sólo una función, tienes que instanciarla para que `hasOwnProperty` te de los resultados que esperas, esto porque la línea `console.log(A.hasOwnProperty("n"));` debe dar true porque es una propiedad directa del objeto.

Tu última línea da falso porque `hasOwnProperty` solo checa si el objeto mismo tiene esa propiedad, cualquier otra definida desde el prototipo sigue siendo heredada y por eso te manda falso, para que Javascript lo encuentre y  te de true tienes que usar el operador `in`

```js
function A() {
 this.n = 15;
}

A.prototype = {
 b: 2,
 c: 3
};

var test = new A();

Function.prototype.nn = 15;

Object.prototype.bb = 305;

console.log("test property n: "+test.hasOwnProperty("n")); // true porque es propiedad directa

console.log("test property b: "+test.hasOwnProperty("b")); // Falso porque declaramos su prototipo

console.log("text property nn: " + test.hasOwnProperty("nn")); //False porque la propiedad se definió para Function y no para Object

console.log("text property bb: " + test.hasOwnProperty("bb")); //False porque hasOwnProperty no busca en el prototipo de manera extensiva

console.log("nn in text: " + ("nn" in test)); //False porque la propiedad se definió para Function y no para Object, aún usando el operador `in`

console.log("bb in text: " + ("bb" in test)); //True porque el operador `in` busca de manera extensiva
```

Comment: Pero la función deberia tener nn ? ya que Funcion.prototype es su prototipo ? , entonces cuales son las propias propiedades de un Constructor en este caso?

Comment: osea cual es la propiedad directa del constructor?

Comment: Vendrá siendo todo lo que definas adentro de `function A(){}` esas serán las propiedades directas de tu objeto A, y que `hasOwnProperty` podrá buscar sin problemas, todo lo demás que se agregue a `.prototype` es heredado y `hasOwnProperty` no lo encontrará.

Comment: no ,porque me marca "n" como false el A.hasOwnProperty

Comment: `A.hasOwnProperty` siempre te dará false sin importar que le mandes, porque ese método es exclusivo de objetos es decir ya una instancia de tu función, más no las funciones mismas.

Comment: ah gracias, podrías darme documentación de eso que me dices del false

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/hasOwnProperty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445261/why-does-hasownproperty-not-recognise-functions-on-an-objects-prototype

Comment: mm no me respondes mucho, porque he leído que el Constructor también es un objeto

Comment: @Lixus Una función en JS es también un objeto, por lo tanto si posee una propiedad puede ser comprobado con una llamada a `hasOwnProperty()`. Ejecuta lo siguiente y verás si da `true` o no para una función: `function A() {this.n = 15;}` `A.propiedad = 0;` `A.hasOwnProperty("propiedad")`

Comment: me referiero a : A.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty("nn"); //=> true

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Ya te lo he respondido.